# Comparing strings in android

Tags: java, android

I want to compare a string literal that is "failed" to a string that has been passed to this function, but my problem is that the string that is passed "result" is not the same as the string fail, and i explicitly passed "failed" to the function.

```
       if(result.equals(fail))
```

always returns false for me

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 super.onPostExecute(result);   
 TextView data_details = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results_tab);
 data_details.setText(result); // THIS PRINTS OUT THE VALUE TO SCREEN WHICH IS 'failed'
 String fail = "failed";

 if(result.equals(fail))
 {

    Intent redirect = new Intent(LogActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    redirect.putExtra("error", result);
    startActivity(redirect);
    finish();
  }     
 }
```

And also I tried:

```
if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("failed"))
```

Comment: this `if(result.equalsIgnoreCase(""failed))` will give u compiler error. I would do `"failed".equalsIgnoreCase(result)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your String variables might contain white spaces, i suggest you to check if condition as follows,

```
if(result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(fail.trim()))
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: No need to trim fail string because there is no space in string.

Comment: @ChiragRaval agree, but at run time sometime if memory problem occurs then it may contain white space too, so for double the checking i used trim() to both the variable for perfect result.

Comment: That worked, and i would not have thought about using trim because the String result has no whitespace before or after it, but it was passed from another file so i guess that is where it came from. thanks for the replies

Comment: @kabuto178 yes, it is always advisable to use trim() method when working with String variables :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `fail.equals(result.trim())`
There may be possibility that `result` contains a space because of which is it causing issues.

**Reason here *fail* is used for comparison is in your case *it can be never null*. If result is null you will get *NullPointerException***